# Java Understanding of getSource() & action listener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, actionevent

i'm trying to learn more about actionListeners.

I try to print out the message "Test Action", if the button "save" is clicked.
Anyway, i don't get it at all.

Here is my code, hope anyone can help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class applet extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5561312464056465383L;
    private JTextField txtNameEingeben;
    private JTextField txtPwEingeben;

    public applet() {
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        JLabel lblANewLabel = new JLabel("Name");
        lblANewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        lblANewLabel.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        lblANewLabel.setBounds(33, 57, 117, 37);
        lblANewLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.add(lblANewLabel);
        //TEXTFELD NAME
        txtNameEingeben = new JTextField();
        txtNameEingeben.setText("");
        txtNameEingeben.setBounds(162, 64, 134, 28);
        panel.add(txtNameEingeben);
        txtNameEingeben.setColumns(10);
        //TEXTFELD PASSWORT
        txtPwEingeben = new JTextField();
        txtPwEingeben.setText("");
        txtPwEingeben.setBounds(162, 113, 134, 28);
        panel.add(txtPwEingeben);
        txtPwEingeben.setColumns(10);
        //LABEL ÜBERSCHRIFT
        JLabel lblNamePasswort = new JLabel("Name & Passwort in einem Array     speichern");
        lblNamePasswort.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblNamePasswort.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblNamePasswort.setBounds(0, 23, 450, 16);
        panel.add(lblNamePasswort);
        JButton btnSave = new JButton("save");
        btnSave.setBounds(308, 251, 117, 29);
        panel.add(btnSave);
        btnSave.addActionListener(new events());    
    }

    public void save(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Button gedrückt.");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource(btnSave)) {
            System.out.println("Test Action");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        applet applet1 = new applet();
        applet1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Anyway, i don't get it at all." Please make a better description of the problem.

Comment: shouldn't `if (event.getSource(btnSave)) {` be `if (event.getSource() == btnSave) {`

Comment: btnSave.addActionListener(new events());    . What is events?. It should be btnSave.addActionListener(this);

Comment: what is `new events()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. don't to use reserved Java class and method names as the name of your project. `public class applet extends...` should be `public class MyApplet extends....`,
2. use proper [Java Naming Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)
3. use `JFrame` instead of `JApplet`, create `JFrame` as local variable instead of extends JFrame, similair as for `private JTextField txtNameEingeben;`
4. use [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) instead of `AbsoluteLayout (setBounds(...))`
5. from `btnSave.addActionListener(new events());` the `events()` isn't declared
6. you should use `event.getSource() == btnSave` instead of `event.getSource(btnSave)`
7. read the Oracle tutorial about [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: 6, i rather prefer use annonymous class if this actionListener is only  for this button

Comment: @nachokk yes right or Swing Action, but in this form (annonymous class or Swing Action) will be just empty info for OP

Comment: +1 for favoring composition over inheritance, but the bad thing of this in swing components is for example if you use a guieditor like matisse you can't design it if you don't extend it.

Answer (score 2):

ActionEvent#getSource() delivers the component responsible for firing. In case of buttons, Swing puts the button itself as a source. This means, that you need to check if the button is the source. There are two possibilities to do it in your code:

1. Make button to a field:

   ```
   public class applet extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

     /**
    * 
    */
     private static final long serialVersionUID = -5561312464056465383L;
     private JTextField txtNameEingeben;
     private JTextField txtPwEingeben;

     private JButton btnSave;

     /**
      * Create the applet.
      */
     public applet() {

       ...

       lblNamePasswort.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
       lblNamePasswort.setBounds(0, 23, 450, 16);
       panel.add(lblNamePasswort);

       btnSave = new JButton("save");
       btnSave.setBounds(308, 251, 117, 29);
       panel.add(btnSave);
       btnSave.addActionListener(this);

     }

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
       if (btnSave.equals(event.getSource())) {
         save();
       }
     }

     public void save() {
       System.out.println("Button gedrückt.");
     }
     ...
   ```

   }
2. A nicer way to implement it, is not to let the whole applet to implement Action listener, but just use inline implementations.

   ```
         public class applet extends JApplet {

           private static final long serialVersionUID = -5561312464056465383L;
           private JTextField txtNameEingeben;
           private JTextField txtPwEingeben;

           /**
            * Create the applet.
            */
           public applet() {
             getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));

             // left out
             ...              

             JButton btnSave = new JButton("save");
             btnSave.setBounds(308, 251, 117, 29);
             panel.add(btnSave);
             btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 save();
               }
             });

           }

           public void save() {
             System.out.println("Button gedrückt.");
           }

           public static void main(String[] args) {
             applet applet1 = new applet();
             applet1.setVisible(true);
           }
         }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace :

```
// (Where 'events' seems to come from nowhere)
btnSave.addActionListener(new events());
```

By :

```
btnSave.addActionListener(
    new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            //if (event.getSource() == btnSave) { // Usefull only in case 2.
                System.out.println("Test Action");
            //}
        }
});
```

Your listener can be:

1. declared like above (anonymously), OR,
2. created by instantiating a class of yours which implements `ActionListener` (look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)).

For option 2. as your embedding class implements ActionListener, you could have passed it as the parameter :

```
btnSave.addActionListener(this);
```

***Note:*** Also you should follow every single recommendation of `mKorbel`.

Comment: your check `event.getSource() == btnSave` is unnecesary and besides event should be e.

Comment: Yep, true. But it would be useful in case the same listener would be used for several Controls (case where we chose to create the class the implements `ActionListener`). So still good for the pedagogic aspect...